# How can I tell unison to first delete files and then to copy changed ones?

Tags: unison

Unison sorts changes in order to first add new files and then to delete removed files.

When I use it to synchronize 2 USB drives, I can have problems with that if there's no room enough in the drives to store new staff without deleting first removed stuff.

So how can I tell unison to perform first deletion and to do anything remains?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for disagreeing, but I don't think Unison behaves like you are describing. According to the Unison manual on [this page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#speeding),
Unison uses rsync with the `--inplace` option as the default copy utility so that updated data is written directly to its destination. You could try specifying these defaults in your profile to see if that helps.

```
copyprog      = rsync --inplace --compress
copyprogrest  = rsync --partial --inplace --compress
copythreshold = 0
sortbysize    = true
```